# javascript does not load with the jquery post method?

Tags: jquery

Greeting to all !!!!!

am new to jquery and using it well... it sounds good...

the problem is when i using ajax post method and append to the original page, the javascript i loaded in the original page is not working the response(appended page some abc.php)...

how to use those ? please help me

success:

```
   function(html)
   {
    $(html).hide().appendTo('#postcomnt').slideDown('slow');
    $('.post_txt_area').val("");
    //alert(html);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear, what are you trying to do.

Are you trying to dynamically load another javascript code and make it work? Then, look here: [JQuery to load Javascript file dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912711/jquery-to-load-javascript-file-dynamically)

Are you trying to bind events to elements that are loaded dynamically? Then take a look at jQuery `live()` method: http://api.jquery.com/live/