# External JS file can't be executed

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a js function that should get some advertisement js code from some server and place it in specified DOM element. It looks like this:

```
function LoadAd(scriptContainer)
{           
    var js = document.createElement("script");
    js.async = true;
    js.src ='someAdUrl';
    var sHolder = document.getElementById(scriptContainer);
    if (sHolder != null) {
        sHolder.appendChild(js);
    }
}
```

the argument 'scriptContainer' is an ID of DOM element, that should contain created js element.

This external js file contains a lot of code that should provide an ad. But this code is never reached and never executed.

When I put this js src directly in html:

```
<script src='someAdUrl'></script>
```

it works fine.
I've checked, the js file is being loaded.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Here is an example of content of js file:

```
document.write('<!-- Some Message -->\n\n<a href="SomeUrl" target=\"_blank\">\n<img width=\"336\" height=\"110\" border=\"0\" src="someImageSource">\n</a>\n');
```

And it always contains `document.write`

Comment: If you add the `<script>` tag directly into the testcode (not including it like above), does it work then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751620/ways-to-add-javascript-files-dynamically-in-a-page

Comment: When do you call the `LoadAd` function? Does it use `document.write`?

Comment: Yes it uses `document.write`, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If the external JS file is being loaded, have you checked whether or not the function is actually being invoked and run?

If the function isn't self-executing and you don't explicitly call it, the code won't run.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code in my case. It may help you

```
var js=document.createElement('script');
js.setAttribute('src','http://domain.com/js/jscpt.js');
document.body.appendChild(js);
```