# How do I add Script in the (head) by jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I add Script in the (head) by jquery

Experimented with this, but did not succeed

```
$("head").append("<script type='text/javascript' src='http//aps.js'></script>");
```

How do I add tag

```
<script></script>
```

in head ??

Comment: Why do you want to add a script block to the head of an already-loaded page? What do you think this will achieve?

Comment: If you want to load dynamically JS files, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751620/ways-to-add-javascript-files-dynamically-in-a-page

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
$(function(){
    var _Script = document.createElement('script');
    _Script .type = 'text/javascript';
    _Script .src = "http//aps.js";
    $("head").append(_Script);
});
```

--- EDIT

Well, on second thought - why do you exactly need to insert script in the head?