# Include jQuery in a JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Sorry for my English, it is not my native tongue...

I have a `my_js.js` file that all my asp pages include.
Now this page needs to use jQuery.
I do not want to add any script tags to my .asp page, i.e. `<script src="jquery.js />`

I want the `my_js.js` to include the jQuery file

I saw an answer in  [How to include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file) (the first answer)
that with JavaScript, it can fail without jQuery

However, this page does not know about jQuery
And that's exactly what I want to do include!!!

Please can someone tell me what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

check **[netplus article](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/for-your-script-loading-needs/)**

in this many solution to add dynamic files

and thanks to [Ways to add javascript files dynamically in a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751620/ways-to-add-javascript-files-dynamically-in-a-page)

or can use simple

```
 document.write('<' + 'script src="' + src + '"' +
                   ' type="text/javascript"><' + '/script>'); // in src path of jquery file
```

and 
you can use **[jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)** function....i think it will be much easier to you wd this to include a js file.

Comment: But that's exactly my problem,
If the browser works asynchronously so my page will load before the alleged JQUeRY it will not work

Answer (score 0):

Give the reference of jquery file 
greaterthan sign and lessthan sign  not wotked in this editor,you replace the world by symbol below example
eg.  /// greaterthan reference path="my_js.js" close lessthan

type this in jquery.js