# Import a JavaScript file from Blogger without Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I tried to retrieve the blogger feeds code without using <script src =
I tried document.write but when import is done the original page content is deleted
Is there a way to import when pressing a button without using <script

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<h1>Test Content</h1>

<script>
function myFunction() {
// The problem here is deleting the text content With document
// And I tried Use document.createElement
// Is there any other way to call and run the file codes ?

 document.open();
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://photoshop4all.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=5&alt=json-in-script&callback=URLAGAIN"><\/script>');

document.close();



  }



  function URLAGAIN(json) {


  document.write(json.feed.entry[0].link[1].href);




    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see : https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/met_doc_open.asp

> The open() method opens an output stream to collect the output from any document.write() or document.writeln() methods.
>
> Once all the writes are performed, the document.close() method causes any output written to the output stream to be displayed.
>
> `Note: If a document already exists in the target, it will be cleared`.
>
> Note: Do not confuse this method with the window.open() method, which opens a new browser window.

you can [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751620/ways-to-add-javascript-files-dynamically-in-a-page) how to insert script whith js