# Display "Loading" Message While Loading External JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

So, I know how to use JS or jQuery, etc., to display a "Loading" message while content is loading.  I have created a fairly large webapp with a number of JS dependencies and I want to display a "loading" message while all the scripts are loading.

My head tag has a number of `<script src=…>` tags in it and I want to display a loading message *instantly* when the user visits the page, and then remove it when all the scripts are loaded.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Then use $ajax function of jquery to download this javascript files and the add script element in head tag after downloading completes.

like this:

```
// display loading message here 

 $ajax("javascriptfile.js",function(file){

  // attach downloaded file to head tag now

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to lazy loading of the script. The last example from this [Lazy Loading](http://www.digital-web.com/extras/lazy_loading/yui_3types.html) show to load .js via YUI. The code from that example is included below for your reference:

```
var HelloWorld = {
    is_loaded: false,
    lazyLoad: function(callback) {
        var loader = new YAHOO.util.YUILoader();
        loader.addModule({
            name: "helloworld",
            type: "js",
            fullpath: "yui_ex/helloworld.js"
        });
        loader.require("helloworld");
        if (callback) {
            loader.onSuccess = callback;
        }
        loader.insert();
    },
    sayIt: function() {
        var args = arguments;
        HelloWorld.lazyLoad(function() { HelloWorld.sayIt.apply(HelloWorld, args); });
    }
};
```

Note that you could possibly load the loading image initially and remove it in the callback function. Reading SO Question [JQuery to load Javascript file dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912711/jquery-to-load-javascript-file-dynamically), you could also use [$.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript) to do the same thing.

You could also find another example in [this link](http://ajaxian.com/archives/lazily-load-functionality-via-unobtrusive-scripts)