# jquery change script src onclick

Tags: jquery

How do I change the src of a script with a click?

```
 <script id="video_load" type="text/javascript" src="something.js"></script>

  <span id="link1">Install</span>

  <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#link1').click(function () {    
              $('#video_load').attr('src','somethingelse.js');      
          });
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: `$.attr` won't change the DOM attribute like I think you are hoping it will. http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Obvious question, do you have a jQuery reference?

Comment: "#link1".click is not a function

Comment: The first script has already run by the time you get to the second script. What do you expect changing the `src` to do? Perhaps you want [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) instead.

Comment: `"#link1".click is not a function` ---> Did you include jQuery ?

Comment: what would be the solution then?

Comment: Depends on what the problem is, if you didn't include jQuery, the solution would be to include jQuery, if you're expecting javascript to dissapear once you change the script tag, the solution would depend entirely on what you're loading, and why you need to replace it etc.

Comment: I have jquery included. I'm calling a video player through the script and I need to change the video that loaded with the click

Comment: Then you should find the dynamically inserted video tag and change the source of that, not the script.

Comment: I have only a script available. To change video I need to change the src of the script.

Comment: No, you need to find the element that is inserted by the script, and either change the source of that element or remove it and then run another script.

Comment: do you know a plugin that could do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you really want to use the jQuery GetScript method.

check out this previously asked question.
[JQuery to load Javascript file dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912711/jquery-to-load-javascript-file-dynamically)

If you then have a good JavaScript structure in your previous file you could just get the object and clear it something like. Assuming it is a global object.

```
Something = {};
```